# ContactEmail field isnot writeable in case

Tags: apex

ContactEmail field isnot writeable in case level.

```
    Id endCustomerAccRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('End Customer').getRecordTypeId();
    Id custContactRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer Contact').getRecordTypeId();

    account   account=new account(name='testing time',recordtypeId=endCustomerAccRecId,Country__c='albania',type='territory');        
    insert account;
    // Insert Contact
    contact  newContact=new contact(LastName='testing user',email='testing@testing.com',recordtypeId=custContactRecId,accountid=account.id);        
    insert  newContact;         


     Case C=new Case();
        C.Status='Pending';
        c.accountId=account.Id;
        c.contactId=newContact.Id;
        C.Type='Incident';
        C.Priority='4-Low';
        C.Description='qwertty';
        C.Subject='xyz';
        c.Sub_Status__c='Waiting on Customer';
    insert c;
    system.debug('------>'+c.ContactEmail); //null
```

How to to provide the value case->contact email

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Email field on Case is not writable. Its values is populated from the email field of Contact record. You just have to assign the contactId on Case object as you are already doing like - c.contactId=newContact.Id;
It will fetch email from Contact record and will populate automatically on Contact Email field of case object. 
Its not a formula field but it behave like that.

Comment: yes right.that I know..in my case email value is null (In system.debug)

Comment: To get the ContactEmail field value, you need to make a query 
ContactEmail field before System.debug statement.


Case c2 = [SELECT ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE ID = : c.Id];
system.debug('------>'+c2.ContactEmail); // testing@testing.com

Answer (score 0):

To get the ContactEmail field value, you need to make a query ContactEmail field before System.debug statement.

```
Case c2 = [SELECT ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE ID = : c.Id]; 
system.debug('------>'+c2.ContactEmail); // testing@testing.com
```